# Getting someone else's browsing history

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, history

If I was interested in knowing what someone else was browsing, could I boot up to a Linux LiveUSB and copy the file off of their computer where Internet Explorer saves history, brink it back to my machine (Linux), and somehow scan through that file for a list of urls visited?

Comment: Why?  Seems a problematic ethically.

Comment: The situation is what my children have been browsing on their own computers. I suspect they've been going to some "inappropriate" sites.

Comment: So, putting it simply, you want to view the Windows Internet Explorer History file on your other Linux computer?

Comment: Sounds like what I am trying to do, yes.

Comment: What Operating System is on the machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work in Linux (as they are Windows applications, they could be run under Wine) but [BrowsingHistoryView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/browsing_history_view.html), by NirSoft, should do the trick. The following are the relevant properties of the software:

> - Reads the history data of 4 different Web browsers (Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, and Safari) and displays the browsing history of all these Web browsers in one table.
> - Allows you to watch the browsing history of all user profiles in a running system, as well as to get the browsing history from external hard drive.

For Internet Explorer and most recent Windows versions, the history file (`Index.dat`) is located at:

> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History

Where `%userprofile%` is a variable that redirects to `C:\Users\ -username-`

---

With this being said, I would advise ***against*** using any data one may find within those history files (at least, in the way it is perceived). Besides being (as pointed out by mpdc) ethically questionable and, in a way, a breach of privacy, a good technical reason for this are that ad and popup pages also appear on the History, creating a sort of false positives. Also, History entries can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the account holder for your internet provider, some companies provide a service whereby they can track all of the addresses accessed by the various ips on your network.